# Insert Google Calendar events using PHP API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I know that there are many questions related to this topic but trust me I have tried quite a lot of them and I am unable to get this working.

Whats I want is, User will click on a button to set the appointment which will be saved to my Google calendar. So when the user clicks a button, they see a popup with some calendar including options to set time also. After they have selected a date and time, it will make an API call which will insert the event using the selected date and time to my Google calendar. Is this possible?

I have tried using the CURL post but it says "Login required". My Curl POST looks like this:

```
$dataarray = array(
"created"   => "2018-04-11T07:02:25.000Z",
"creator"   => array(
                "displayName"   => "First Last",
                "description"   => "Added via CURL for testing",
                "email"         => "test@testcompanies.com"
),
"end"       => array(
                "dateTime"      => "2018-05-08T14:30:00+05:30",
                "timeZone"      => "Asia/Calcutta"
),
"start"     => array(
                "dateTime"      => "2018-05-08T13:30:00+05:30",
                "timeZone"      => "Asia/Calcutta"
),
"location"  => "Siliguri",
"reminders" => array(
                "useDefault"        => "true"
),
);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{my-calendar-id}/events?key={API_KEY}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dataarray));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$response = json_decode($server_output);
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction with some good examples so that I can learn and get this working.

Comment: When the API key is used for this situation, ``"message": "Login Required"`` occurs. Unfortunately, inserting events cannot be done using API key. Please use the access token.

Comment: use the provided Google PHP libraries instead of trying to make your own HTTP requests..it's much simpler and more reliable. And also read the API docs and understand about the authorisation requirements. It seems you didn't do too much research into this? See https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth and https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/ . BTW if you want another user to be inserting things into _your_ google account, make sure you use the Service Account feature so it always connects to your google account, and not the end user's.

Comment: @ADyson I got it working. Thanks Man!!! I read documents in details about the auth request and go that working.